# Tk_PhotoPutBlock does not render my svg file correctly

Tags: c, image, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to implement this [example](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/resvg/blob/master/crates/c-api/examples/cairo/example.c) written in C with C Tk API.
My objective is to try to use this [library](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/resvg) to transform an `svg` file into a photo Tk to be read in frame Tk. Below is my svg file :

```
<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="32" cx="35" cy="65" fill="#F00" opacity="0.5"/>
  <circle r="32" cx="65" cy="65" fill="#0F0" opacity="0.5"/>
  <circle r="32" cx="50" cy="35" fill="#00F" opacity="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

and my C code :

```
    Tk_PhotoHandle source;
    unsigned char *imgData;

    // PhotoObj : set photo [image create photo]; # tcl code
    // FileObj  : file.svg

    source = Tk_FindPhoto(interp, Tcl_GetString(PhotoObj));

    if (source == NULL) {
        Tcl_SetResult(interp, "photo not found", TCL_STATIC);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    char *sp = Tcl_GetString(FileObj);

    resvg_init_log;
    resvg_options *opt = resvg_options_create();
    resvg_options_load_system_fonts(opt);
    resvg_render_tree *tree;
    int err = resvg_parse_tree_from_file(sp, opt, &tree);
    resvg_options_destroy(opt);

    if (err != RESVG_OK) {
        printf("Error id: %i\n", err);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    resvg_size size = resvg_get_image_size(tree);
    int width = (int)size.width;
    int height = (int)size.height;
    
    imgData = (unsigned char *)Tcl_Alloc(width*height*4);

    if (imgData == NULL) {
    Tcl_SetResult(interp, "cannot alloc image buffer", TCL_STATIC);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    resvg_render(tree, resvg_transform_identity(), width, height, imgData);

    Tk_PhotoImageBlock block;
    Tk_PhotoGetImage(source, &block);

    block.pixelPtr   = imgData;
    block.width      = width;
    block.height     = height;
    block.pitch      = width * 4;
    block.pixelSize  = 4;
    block.offset[0]  = 0;
    block.offset[1]  = 1;
    block.offset[2]  = 2;
    block.offset[3]  = 3;

    if (Tk_PhotoSetSize(interp, source, width, height) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    Tk_PhotoPutBlock(interp, source, &block, 0, 0, width, height, TK_PHOTO_COMPOSITE_SET);
    resvg_tree_destroy(tree);

    return TCL_OK;
```

[image: result].

As you can see, the colours in the left-hand svg are not the same as those in the Tk right image.
Maybe the problem comes from my `imgData` variable, the author in his example seems to be retransforming the data for a cairo surface. My knowledge of image transformation is fairly limited, so I don't know what to do on the `Tk` side.

Comment: Can you make a debugging output for the program that prints out the result of `resvg_render` result, and then the other result after `PhotoSetSize` ? This looks to me very much like some wrong assumption in the blending or rendering, so it might be best to start by bisecting which library call actually creates the problem (programs sometimes e.g. assume that they are painting atop a black surface, thus the transparent colors come out dark).

Comment: @exa The underlying data model of a photo image is 8-bits-per-channel RGBA; it doesn't assume the background is any colour. I do not know if the bug being reported is in the SVG renderer (not code I know), or the main photo renderer (possible, but nobody's found it), or even in the asker's expectation.

Comment: Could you add screenshots of what you think it ought to look like and what it actually looks like? Also, check whether exporting the photo as a PNG and importing it in another image viewer works. Like that, we stand a chance of figuring this out!

Comment: @DonalFellows , I do not have enough privilege to post a photo directly, you can take a look at the link named `result`

Comment: `$photo write my.png -format PNG` produces the same thing as the image in my frame. The link of my [image](https://imgur.com/a/lQm9Bvb)

Comment: The author does [this](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/resvg/blob/67ca118f47fba6b65550c40635e56207a159ca4d/crates/c-api/examples/cairo/example.c#L42-L48) I don't know if I should apply the same thing.

Comment: Are you aware of [tksvg](https://github.com/oehhar/tksvg), which will be included in Tk 8.7 and later? Using that, I'm getting colors similar to your left image.

Comment: OK, so the colours are darker than expected.

Comment: @SchelteBron, Yes I know, but I think this library is better, for the text in particular.

Comment: I'm *guessing* that something is applying the alpha wrongly, but I don't know where the problem is (SVG->model, model->display, or both). I certainly suspect the application of the alpha during model->display, given that there have been issues reported with that in the past (but nothing actionable, alas). I *want* this fixed!

Comment: @DonalFellows, after a discussion with the author, this library uses premultiplied alpha, while Tk, as it seems, uses non-premultiplied.

Answer (score 1):

I've *finally* gotten around to testing this properly; I created an SVG file with exactly the contents you suggested, and then ran this script:

```
puts [info patchlevel]

image create photo foo -file svgtestimg.svg
foo write svgtestimg.png

pack [label .foo -background white -image foo]
pack [label .foo2 -background black -image foo]
```

That reported that I ran `Tcl: 9.0a4, Tk: 9.0b1` (yes, a weird mix; my development machine is not in wholly consistent state)

The screenshot of the output is this:

[image: screenshot]

And the generated PNG is this:

[image: svgimgtest.png]

I also looked at all images using several image viewing tools (browsers). The *result* of this experiment is that I know that Tk rendering the SVG correctly (or at least very close to it), both with a light and a dark background, and that the underlying image model has the correct data because the PNG (with transparency) is being written correctly. This is a *tremendous* relief to me!

So what's going on with your problem? Well, I'm using the built-in SVG renderer in Tk 8.7 (9.0 is essentially the same) that is fully aware of the photo image's internal RGBA model, and you're using some other SVG renderer (resvg) that seems to make assumptions about what the background colour of the image should be. Those assumptions (which appear to be slanted towards the darker end) are obviously wrong; photos are full RGBA and the compositing with the background can be left to Tk.

I'm not sure whether this is a fault in resvg or in how you are using it; it's entirely possible that a suitable option would make it behave correctly. I don't know it well enough to say for sure.

---

Thank you for asking this question! It's prompted me to test Tk in this area a bit more thoroughly; I'm now reasonably sure that Tk is doing the right thing. I had wondered because we definitely have had some reported problems with this in the past, yet they've been frustratingly difficult to hunt down! This case was simple enough that I could cross-check it properly and understand that the results were definitely as expected.

I've no control over what third-party code does, and I'm not going to speculate on how to mend it.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer this. My build of Tk was in a *very* weirdly broken state, so I kept finding other things to do instead...

Comment: ok , the problem doesn't come from the library I'm using but from what I do with the data's library in order to use it in Tk, as I said in my previous comment, I have to rework the data to works. _'Sorry for taking so long to answer this'_ : No problem, thank you for your reply, even if it's late.